# Clear part of associative array

Tags: bash, shell, loops, associative-array

Must I use a loop to clear some data in an associative array,  or is there a faster & better option?

currently I'm using:

```
until [[ $ploop1 -eq 99 ]]; do  ##do044
    ((++ploop1))
    hnr[$ploop1,2]=0
    hnr[$ploop1,3]=0
    hnr[$ploop1,4]=0
    hnr[$ploop1,5]=0
done  ##do044
```

Observe that ,0 and,1 shouldn't be cleared

Comment: an inner loop would be easier, especially if there are a lot of numbers, eg:  `for x in {2..5}; do hnr[$ploop,$x]=0; done`; and if you want to remove/delete the elements: `unset hnr[$ploop,3]` or in the loop `unset hnr[$ploop,$x]` or even `unset hnr[$ploop,{2..5}]`; I'm not aware of a way to do something like `hnr[$ploop,{2..5}]=0` (not saying it can't be done, I'm just not aware of a way)

Comment: @markp-fuso but I still need to put those inside a loop to get the $ploop number counting?

Comment: right, 2 loops: outer loop: `until [[ ... ]]; do ((++ploop1)); <inner_loop>; done` and the inner loop: `for x in {2..5}; do hnr[$ploop,$x]=0; done`; or if you want to `unset` the elements you could replace the inner loop with `unset hnr[$ploop,{2..5}]`

Comment: @markp-fuso so unset=clear data in current specified location in the array?

Comment: you've mentioned `clear the data` but you're not actually clearing the data ... you're setting the data to `0`, ie, the array element still exists; on the other hand ... `unset` will wipe out, remove, delete, nuke the array element, ie, the array element no longer exists; and fwiw ... just figured out that `eval hnr[$ploop,{2..5}]=0` seems to work (ie, the 4 array elements are **set** to `0`), though keep in mind some folks will likely pooh-pooh the idea of using `eval`, ymmv ...

Comment: @markp-fuso no, I didn't clear the data in my script because I didn't know how, until now, but I don't need to redeclare the array, I can just start to fill it again?

Comment: correct, by unsetting the elements but **NOT** the array then the array declaration remains in place, so no need to be re-declare; I've rolled all of my comments into a single answer for readability; you can run `typeset -p hnr` before and after to see how the array elements are set to `0` (zero) or completed removed (ie, `unset`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidating my comments into one area ...

OP has mentioned 'clear the data' but is really setting the array elements to `0` (zero).  If OP has a list of numbers to process then something like the following should also work:

```
until [[ $ploop1 -eq 99 ]]; do
    ((++ploop1))
    for x in {2..5}            # or `x in 2 3 4 5` or `x in {2..4} 5` or ...
    do
        hnr[$ploop1,$x]=0
    done
done
```

If OP doesn't mind using `eval` this can be shortened a bit to:

```
until [[ $ploop1 -eq 99 ]]; do
    ((++ploop1))
    eval hnr[$ploop1,{2..5}]=0 
done
```

Now, if OP wants to `clear` the elements as in `remove the elements`, then this should work ...

```
until [[ $ploop1 -eq 99 ]]; do
    ((++ploop1))
    unset hnr[$ploop1,{2..5}]
done
```

... and as long as the `unset` is issued against array elements and **NOT** the array (ie, `unset hnr`) then the array declaration remains intact/valid, ie, no need to re`declare -A` the array.

---

Adding Philippe's question/comment:

If the entire purpose of OPs loop is to **just** unset the array elements then the following should eliminate the need for a loop:

```
unset hnr[{0..99},{2..5}]
```

**NOTE**: OP can adjust the numbers based on actual ranges in use ...

Comment: How about `unset hnr[{0..99},{2..5}]` ?

Comment: @Philippe sure, that should work, too; and would certainly make OP's code even smaller ... I just assumed OP might have something more planned for the outer loop and the decremented `$ploop1` variable; I've added your question/comment to the answer; thanks

Comment: `until ((ploop1++ == 99)); do declare "$(printf "hrr["$ploop1,"%d]=0 " {2..5})"; done` and `until ((ploop1++ == 99)); do unset hnr["$ploop1,"{2..5}]; done` This avoids using the evil `eval`.